# Can I get vim to treat a .hive file the same way it treats a .sql one?

Tags: vim

When I open a file in vim with a .sql extension I get handy syntax highlighting relevant to sql.

However, when I open a file with extension .hive the text are all just a single color.

Is nit possible to tell vim to treat .hive extension the same as .sql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along these lines in your vimrc should probably do the trick:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.hive set filetype=sql
```